# jQuery load() when on a different tab

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

So I have my load script in jQuery:

```
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/urltoload.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Using a `setInterval`, how can I check if a user is not on the on the page?

Comment: I formatted your code, but you're missing `);` and `}` from the end.

Comment: You can't, but you can check if the [window is active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have correctly understand your question, you can check if the user "is on" the page and when leave it with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $([window, document]).focusin(function(){
      //Your logic when the page gets active
   }).focusout(function(){
      //Your logic when the page gets inactive
   });
});
```

Another solution, maybe a little more "intricated", is to check the mouse movements (http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/#fn) each N seconds.

If you have cross-browsing issue, you can check this answer that gives a good workaround for differents browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/1720344

**UPDATE**
The pseudocode to a timeout function is this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

By your comment, I think is best to "around" the sub-function and not the `$(document).ready()` (I haven't done before, timeouting the `document.ready`, but you can try and see what it happens ;) - I believe that this function is simple called after N seconds from the `document.ready`)

With a timeout of 2 seconds, you can do something like that (but I haven't tested it):

```
$(document).ready(setTimeout(function(){
       $([window, document]).focusin(function(){
          //Your logic when the page gets active
       }).focusout(function(){
          //Your logic when the page gets inactive
       });
    }, 2000));
```

Comment: @damosier, could this be turned into a function with a setTimeout on the document.ready ?

Comment: @jordanzhninja I have given you a possible solution, but I haven't test it

Comment: ok thankan yougen to be honest i have no idea how to do what im trying to do because i need the page title to change when a new comment arrives (found in the mibbit.com ajax irc client) but i dont know how

Comment: @jordanzhninja to change the page title you can call this function __$(document).attr('title', 'new_page_title');__. Checking when a new comment arrives, if the comment is "placed" on another website or server, you can call it with a timeout and check when something change from the previous call (so you know when there is a new comment)

Comment: dont worry i have sorted it

Answer (score 1):

With `$(window).focus()` you could check if the browser is active.

```
$(window).focus(function(){
  // interval here
});
```